# JWPlayer CEA-608/708 captions styling

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, closed-captions

I am trying to dynamically set caption style like font Size, font color, background color and font family. Following is the code snippet;

```
jwplayer().setCaptions({"color":"#FF0000","fontSize": 14});
```

This is working Chrome, but does not work on EDGE and FIREFOX. On IE11 closed caption are not displayed.

Is this a bug or is CC 608 support not uniform across different browsers?

Following are the versions:

- JWPlayer: 7.9.3+commercial_v7-9-3.158
- Microsoft Edge: 38.14393.0.0
- Firefox: 52.0 (32-bit)
- Chrome: 56.0.2924.87
- IE: 11.953.14393.0

Comment: I thought currently the default for most browsers is to display `subtitles` (which per W3C spec are not styled), rather than styled CEA-608 complaint `captions`. Last time I needed to display styled captions we ended up writing our own overlay

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when not using Flash, the CEA-608 styling depends on ::cue pseudo-element. see here github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/1813